# how to implode two arrays into one single string for inserting mysql values?

Tags: php, form-submit

i have two arrays being gathered from form inputs both text and images

```
$final = array($info, $paths);
print_r($final);
```

this prints

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => '1995', [1] => 'chevrolet', [2] => 'impala', [3] => '5.7', [4] => 'bose', [5] => '165465', [6] => 'sadfasdf', [7] => '', [8] => '', [9] => 'asdfasdasdf', [10] => '', [11] => '', [12] => 'sdafasdfasd', [13] => '', [14] => '', [15] => '', [16] => '', [17] => 'asdfasdf', ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 'images/picture22677.png', [1] => 'images/picture22678.png', [2] => 'images/picture22679.jpg', ) )
```

PERFECT!
but how do i now convert this `$final` array into a single string like this

```
'$value', '$value', '$value', '$value',
```

but with out the array key number
 to better understand me i need a string i can finnaly insert into mysql like so

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO 
    auto(year, make, model, engine, sound_system, mileage, att1, att2,
    att3, att4, att5, att6, att7, att8, att9, att10, att11, att12, att13, att14, att15,    picture1,
    picture2, picture3, picture4, picture5, picture6, picture7, picture8, picture9,
    picture10, picture11, picture12)
    VALUES 
    ($finalpaths));
```

see for `VALUES ($finalpaths));` here is where i need to have the array list into a string that would work in this case

i hope you understood what i need, thanks for any input:)

Comment: What is the purpose of having the 2-level array, and how does that convert to your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do, is use a prepared statement in PDO or mysqli. It protects you from sql injection and the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.

Then your sql would look like (I normally prefer named variables like `:year`, etc. but this would work as well):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO 
    auto(year, make, model, engine, sound_system, mileage, att1, att2,
    att3, att4, att5, att6, att7, att8, att9, att10, att11, att12, att13, att14, att15,    picture1,
    picture2, picture3, picture4, picture5, picture6, picture7, picture8, picture9,
    picture10, picture11, picture12)
    VALUES 
    (?, ?, ?, ..., ?, ?, ?)";    // as many question marks as variables
```

and in PDO you would [`execute`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) (see the manual for complete examples) it like:

```
// assuming that $dbh contains your PDO database connection
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute($final[0]);
```

Comment: wow thats complicated i havent digged in pdo much yet, any other way to do it in normal php?

Comment: @sdfasdfad It's not that much different from your way and you avoid the whole escaping part. And it is the current *normal php* way :)

Comment: @sdfasdfad PDO is normal php and is easier then mysql_* not to mention safer  !

Comment: Note that [prepared statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496) are not specific to PDO. The mysqli functions support prepared statements as well. That being said, there ARE options to do this without prepared statements that are just as safe.

Comment: @sdfasdfad Just post back here or in a new question if you run into any specific problems, you'll have it working in no time at all.

Comment: @sdfasdfad What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

While [prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496) are a better way to handle this, it is also possible to do something like this (assuming you're using the `mysqli_*` functions).

```
$items = array_merge($final[0], $final[1]);
$safeItems = array_map($items, 'mysqli_real_escape_string'); 
$sqlString = "'" . join("', '", $safeItems) . "'";
```

We're using [`array_merge()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) to join the two parts of `$final` into a single array. Alternatively, we could build from the original values like this: `$items = array_merge($info, $paths)`.

We're using [`array_map()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to call
[`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) in order to properly escape each value to prevent SQL injection

We're using [`join()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.join.php) to combine everything together into the final output.

That being said, it looks like you're actually using the `mysql_*` functions. There's very good reasons why these functions should **not** be used. See here for more details: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)